# Django changing the default object manager

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to change the default object manager for all Models? (which would include the object managers on third party apps)

Answer (score 2):

The default manager is attached in the function `ensure_default_manager` in `django.db.models.manager`. It attaches by default a manager of class `Manager`. You could monkeypatch this function to attach a different (subclass of) `Manager`.

But you have to consider whether this is the most ideal solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do that modify the django code itself. Monkey patching is an option also, there are a lot of techniques for that out there.